# Node js equivalent to Python utf8, Sha1, base64

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, utf-8, base64, sha1

I have this piece of code in python3

```
payload = 'my URI'
payload_utf8 = payload.encode("utf-8")
print(payload_utf8) 
payload_sha1 = hashlib.sha1(payload_utf8).digest()
print(payload_sha1)
payload_base64 = base64.b64encode(payload_sha1)
print(payload_base64)
```

I want the same result but in node.js. I have tried this

```
const payload = "my URI";
    console.log(payload);
    const payload_UTF8 = utf8.encode(payload);
    console.log(payload_UTF8);
    const payload_Sha = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(payload_UTF8).digest()
    console.log(payload_Sha);
const payload_Base64 = Buffer.from(payload_Sha).toString('base64');
```

But the results isn't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are the same, the only difference is that in the python example you're returning a byte array and in the Js example, you're returning a string. If you want to get the exact same result in string format you can use `print(payload_base64.decode("utf-8"))`.

Comment: Im using it to create a payload in a JWT. But the token doesn't come out the same.. Is there something i can do? If you know of course

Comment: Without more information about your code I can't really provide a solution. However you can use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to decode both of the generated jwt tokens, and see what the differences is. **Note**: it doesn't really matter if both jwt are different, you just have to make sure you provide the same payload for both and check if its correct. e.g. if use pyjwt and json-webtoken I can see that the headers are in a different order which is probably the cause of the two tokens being different. So i'd say you shouldn't compare two different libraries with eachother, but focus on the payload